# What is this Electron Forge ERROR in Electron's template (Typescript + Webpack)?

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, electron, electron-forge

I installed Electron's template following [Electron Forge page](https://www.electronforge.io/templates/typescript-+-webpack-template).

```
npx create-electron-app my-new-app --template=typescript-webpack
```

After that, I run

```
npm run start
```

insides `my-new-app` folder and the following error message were popped up in command window

```
$ npm run start

> my-new-app@1.0.0 start
> electron-forge start

✔ Checking your system
✔ Locating Application

An unhandled rejection has occurred inside Forge:
Error: Expected plugin to either be a plugin instance or a { name, config } object but found @electron-forge/plugin-webpack,[object Object]

Electron Forge was terminated. Location:
{}
```

I Google it, but no one encoutered same error.
I could use above template without error message before a week ago. So, I copy the project that were made a week ago and run. It was success. However, I run the following command

```
npm audit
```

There are 22 vulnerabilities (3 moderate, 19 high).
Errors are

```
got  <11.8.5 
Severity: moderate
```

and

```
minimatch  <3.0.5
Severity: high
```

It could not fix by `npm audit fix` and `npm audit fix --force`. So, I fixed this error by rewriting `package.json` and `package-lock.json`. Then I deleate `node_modules` folder and run `npm install`.
These vulnerabilities are gone, but above my problem were again after I run `npm run start`.

I think problem is involved in `@electron-forge/plugin-webpack`.
However, I dont know how to fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The plugins field, under `config.forge` options in package.json, were generated in the following strucure:

```json
"plugins": [
  [
    "@electron-forge/plugin-webpack",
    {
      "mainConfig": "./webpack.main.config.js",
      "renderer": {
        "config": "./webpack.renderer.config.js",
        "entryPoints": [
          {
            "html": "./src/index.html",
            "js": "./src/renderer.ts",
            "name": "main_window",
            "preload": {
              "js": "./src/preload.ts"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
]
```

Change that structure to an object with `name` and `config` fields:

```json
"plugins": [
  {
    "name": "@electron-forge/plugin-webpack",
    "config": {
      "mainConfig": "./webpack.main.config.js",
      "renderer": {
        "config": "./webpack.renderer.config.js",
        "entryPoints": [
          {
            "html": "./src/index.html",
            "js": "./src/renderer.ts",
            "name": "main_window",
            "preload": {
              "js": "./src/preload.ts"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: i got this error seemingly without updating my library.  warning for others.  thank you for help

Answer (score 2):

Modifying the plugin syntax will only fix the issue when you run it locally.
If you export the package using `npm run make`, it will only display a white blank screen.

Try the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74248880/6727767) if you face such an issue

Comment: Thnk you for your sharing!!! I appreciate!

Answer (score 1):

This was a problem in Electron Forge beta 73 or whichever version this user was running - the bug has since been fixed