# electron-forge: npm run make creates an app with a white screen

Tags: electron, electron-forge

I created a template with `npx create-electron-app my-new-app --template=typescript-webpack` (from https://www.electronforge.io/templates/typescript-+-webpack-template). I adapted the package.json like this (in order to get rid of an error):

```json
"plugins": [
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/plugin-webpack",
          "config": {
            "mainConfig": "./webpack.main.config.js",
            "renderer": {
              "config": "./webpack.renderer.config.js",
              "entryPoints": [
                {
                  "html": "./src/index.html",
                  "js": "./src/renderer.ts",
                  "name": "main_window",
                  "preload": {
                    "js": "./src/preload.ts"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
```

When I run npm run make, electron forge builds an app that has a white screen(missing all the content).

Update: after installing `npm install -g @electron-forge/cli@beta`
and running `electron-forge make` instead of `npm run make` I get this:

```json
✔ Checking your system
✖ Resolving Forge Config

Electron forge was terminated:
Expected plugin to either be a plugin instance or [string, object] but found [object Object]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the latest `@electron-forge` version.

Please follow the below steps to resolve this issue.

1. Delete the below files and folders

```
package-lock.json
node_modules
.webpack
```

2. Change all the `@electron-forge` versions in packages.json to `6.0.0-beta.63`.

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@electron-forge/cli": "6.0.0-beta.63",
    "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "6.0.0-beta.63",
    "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "6.0.0-beta.63",
    "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "6.0.0-beta.63",
    "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "6.0.0-beta.63",
    "@electron-forge/plugin-webpack": "6.0.0-beta.63",
```

Make sure you do not have `^` in front of the version numbering. Or else, it will fetch the latest version.

3. Modify the plugins section as shown below.

```
"plugins": [
        [
          "@electron-forge/plugin-webpack",
          {
            "mainConfig": "./webpack.main.config.js",
            "renderer": {
              "config": "./webpack.renderer.config.js",
              "entryPoints": [{
                "name": "main_window",
                "html": "./src/index.html",
                "js": "./src/renderer.ts",
                "preload": {
                  "js": "./src/preload.ts"
                }
              }]
            }
          }
        ]
      ]
```

4. Now install the packages

```
npm install
```

or, if you use yarn

```
yarn install
```

5. Now you should be able to see the page when you do an `npm run make`.

Comment: For me, it was enough to only apply steps 2 and 4. No need to modify configs or remove any files. The last working version is beta.67.

Comment: I agree with @Rychu . That worked for me too.